# What is the purpose of TreeView.isTreeNode

Tags: qt, qml

The TreeView attaches some properties to its delegate. One of them is *isTreeNode*. The [documentation](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qml-qtquick-treeview.html) writes about isTreeNode:

> required property bool isTreeNode -  Is true if the delegate item represents a node in the tree. Only one
> column in the view will be used to draw the tree, and therefore, only
> delegate items in that column will have this property set to true.  A
> node in the tree should typically be indented according to its depth,
> and show an indicator if hasChildren is true. Delegate items in other
> columns will have this property set to false, and will show data from
> the remaining columns in the model (and typically not be indented).

What is the benefit of this property? For me it looks like an alias for column == 0.

Answer (score 2):

It's currently an alias for column === 0, like you say. But it makes the delegate more readable, and opens up for the possibility to rearrange columns at a later point, and improve the support for right-to-left layouts.